# The website UI does not look fine in safari but looks perfect in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, safari

So there's this problem with the site's UI:
it works fine in Google chrome etc in mobile browsers but when viewing in Apple safari mobile browser, the site's UI gets displaced.
I have tried everything, I guess the margin property is not working in safari. Take a look at Screenshots.

how it looks on android chrome

[image]

Second image is how it looks on safari. and it should be like first image on safari as well

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score -1):

First thing I would think of that try to use a css normalizer

https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Along with a css prefixer to ensure the problem is not from the design

https://autoprefixer.github.io/

In case both of these solutions didn't work please provide a JSFiddle Code in order to help you properly.

Comment: thanks for the links, these wud help in future codes... for now I wrote the CSS for that section again and it worked!